# Why is my SSIS package not getting updated?

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2017, ssdt

I have a Integration Services project within SSDT that has multiple packages. When I right click a single package and choose deploy, SSDT says the operation completed successfully.

However, when I look at the `internal.packages` table within SSISDB on the target server, it does not contain the latest version that I just deployed. Neither the `version_build` field or the `version_guid` field match the values within my package. The SSIS Catalog also displays the incorrect information.

[image]

[image]

It looks to me as though it is not deploying the package at all - except the `internal.projects` table is clearly getting updated with a new time stamp on each deployment, and the `internal.packages` table adds a new row as well.

So, my question is - why is the package not getting updated?

Comment: Do you have the ability to open it up in Visual Studios and run a demo?  What are the results there?  Has it ever worked or did it stop working at a certain point in time?

Comment: If I run the package within SSDT/Visual Studio it runs fine. If I run the deployed version it is definitely running the old implementation.

Comment: Hi @Mr.Brownstone, (same question I've made to @SteveG): On the project properties, is the "TargetServerVersion" set to SQL Server 2017? (Package deployment is supported only from SQL Server 2016 - and the way it behaves depends on "TargetServerVersion")

Comment: @EvandroMuchinski SQL Server 2017 (Enterprise Edition)